# Replace Reference Object Value in PHP SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to echo the image URL in place of the referencedObject. I am getting Referenced Object in correct place but when I am trying to replace it with the image URL corresponding to the referencedObject, the Code isn't being replaced at the correct place, it is displayed about 2 lines above the text.

Using SimpleXML with PHP.

```
<component>
 <section ID="Ld8e0a7b8-429c-4a7d-84ff-8b4698b7adc7">
 <title>DESCRIPTION </title>
 <text>
    <paragraph>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...</paragraph>

   <paragraph>Here is the image 1 </paragraph>
   <paragraph>
       <renderMultiMedia referencedObject="Lc0d31387-d262-4702-8053-0207e1a3fc91"/>
    </paragraph>
   <paragraph>Here is Image 2 , tempor incidid labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </paragraph>
    <paragraph>
      <renderMultiMedia referencedObject="L3dcd8ff8-678a-4e9f-8bb2-d6f3c35d1c10"/>
    </paragraph>
   <paragraph>tempor incidid labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </paragraph>
    <paragraph>tempor incidid labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </paragraph>
    <paragraph/>
</text>
<component>
    <observationMedia ID="Lc0d31387-d262-4702-8053-0207e1a3fc91">
       <text>image description</text>
       <value mediaType="image/jpeg" xsi:type="ED">
          <reference value="Image1.jpg"/>
       </value>
    </observationMedia>
 </component>
 <component>
  <observationMedia ID="L3dcd8ff8-678a-4e9f-8bb2-d6f3c35d1c10">
       <text>image description</text>
       <value mediaType="image/jpeg" xsi:type="ED">
          <reference value="Molecule2.jpg"/>
       </value>
    </observationMedia>
 </component>
</section>
```

Here is how I am getting the values of each id:

```
for($i=0; $i < $pcount; $i++) //$pcount = no. of paragraphs in the xml 
{ 
    $reference_value =  (string) $component->section->component[$i]->observationMedia->value->reference['value'];
    $referencedObject = (string) $component->section->text->paragraph[$i]->renderMultiMedia['referencedObject'];
    $observationMedia_ID = (string) $component->section->component[$i]->observationMedia['ID'];
}
```

Here is the original xml response: [pastebin.com/raw/fnWbifx0](https://pastebin.com/raw/fnWbifx0)

Comment: Here is the original xml response : https://pastebin.com/raw/fnWbifx0

Answer (score 0):

I've used XPath to help finding the relevant data.

I hope I've understood the problem properly, that each `renderMultiMedia` refers to an `observationMedia` object.  This is where I've used XPath to ensure that I find the corresponding data.  You were assuming that the paragraph number match the order of the media information, which is not always correct.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$xml = simplexml_load_file("so.xml");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("d", "urn:hl7-org:v3");
$rmElements = $xml->xpath("//d:renderMultiMedia");
$mediaData = [];
foreach ( $rmElements as $media)
{
    $referencedObject = (string)$media['referencedObject'];
    $mediaElement = $xml->xpath("//d:observationMedia[@ID='$referencedObject']")[0];
    $reference_value =  (string) $mediaElement->value->reference['value'];
    $observationMedia_ID = (string) $mediaElement['ID'];
    $mediaData[] = [ 'referencedObject' => $referencedObject,
            'reference_value' => $reference_value,
            'observationMedia_ID' => $observationMedia_ID
    ];

}
print_r($mediaData);
```

As you can see from the code, I've also changed it to firstly look for any  `renderMultiMedia` elements (the `d:` is there as this takes into account the default namespace set up using the `registerXPathNamespace` method)  then for each one, it cross references the `referencedObject` attribute with the `observationMedia` element.

It builds up an array - but I hope that you can alter it to how you need to work with the data.